# conda updating in background past packages

Tags: anaconda, conda

With latest conda, conda 4.4, when installing a package,
conda is updating in background in pkgs folder older packages (which have been unisntalled previously):

Issues : conda env are not affected, but pkgs folder is taking large space now....

Comment: Have you tried to clean that folder?

Comment: yes, of course, i cleaned many times manually. It keeps downloading in background.

Comment: How did you clean? With the conda clean commands? I'm not sure what the problem is, if cleaning reduces the space taken up...

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

conda clean will do the job of removing unused packages.
Very efficient